# More than 8 outputs detected?

Tags: 13.04, server, kernel

Ever time I log into my Ubuntu Server 13.04 (3.9.9 generic kernel), I see

```
[    2.050256] i915 0000:00:02.0: More than 8 outputs detected
```

beside the `Login:` prompt.

Has anyone seen this before? What does this message mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug in the intel graphics driver that has been fixed for the next release.

See:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65988